# Difference between interceptors and decorators

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, decorator, interceptor

Are there any differences between interceptors and decorators in Java? Strictly speaking, can I implementing things with decorators which are not possible with interceptors and vice versa?

Except the problem that I would have to examine the method name to add method-specific behavior in an interceptor:

Interceptor:

```
@Nice
@Interceptor
public class NiceGreeterInterceptor {
  @AroundInvoke
  public Object decorate(InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {
    Method method = ic.getMethod();
    String methodName = method.getName();
    Object result = ic.proceed();
    if (methodName.equals("greet")) {
      return "NEW " + result;
    }
  }
}
```

Decorator:

```
@Decorator
public class GreeterDecorator implements Greeter {
  @Inject
  @Any
  @Delegate
  private Greeter greeter;

  @Override
  public String greet() {
    return "NEW " + greeter.greet();
  }
}
```

Or is it legitimate to say that I can reproduce all the behavior of decorators with interceptors but it is more comfortable to use decorators?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Decorator

One difference would be, as your example shows it, with decorator one usually writes 1 decorator per 1 decorated class/interface.

#### Decorator example

```
interface Worker {
    void work();
}

class Decorated implements Worker {

    public void work() {

    }
}

class DecoratorByInheritance extends Decorated {

    public void work() {
        // pre
        super.work();
        // post
    }
}

class DecoratorByComposition implements Worker {

    Worker decorated;

    DecoratorByComposition(Worker decorated) {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public void work() {
        // pre
        this.decorated.work();
        // post
    }
}
```

### Interceptor

With interceptors, which are part of the [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) concept, one writes 1 interceptor for a bunch of classes / methods, e.g. intercepting all [DAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) methods and make sure a transaction is open before the invocation and closed after it.

#### Interceptor example

Declare a [pointcut](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts) (what to match), here we match any method from the MyDao class that starts with **insert**, has any arguments and any return type.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.example.dao.MyDao.insert*(..))")
public void insertPointcut() {
}
```

Then we declare an [around advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice) which references the pointcut

```
@Around(value = "com.example.SystemArchitecture.insertPointcut()")
public void interceptMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        // do pre-work
        Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
        // do post work
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Interceptors are more flexible but imagine one changes the method name, if decorator is used, we'll probably get a compiler error, with interceptors, it will just not match and not execute our 'around' logic.

Comment: A decorator is automatically applied to classes that implement the same interface (except using a custom qualifier). So more than one decorated class.

Comment: Agree, it's one to one or one to multiple, but again, you have the interface, so it's heavily object oriented. With AOP, it's more flexible because you can use type filters (e.g. proxy all methods of some class) as well as bare string reg ex matching filters (e.g. proxy all methods that start with select and are part of the com.example.dao package).

Comment: Can you please add your comment to your answer with an example of regex matching filters

Comment: Added, there's no full reg-ex support but you do have some wildcard matching.

Comment: Thanks. So theoretically I can reproduce all the behavior of decorators with interceptors?

Comment: Well that is a good point. When you add it to your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

In general, a decorator is used to add new functionality or modify existing functionality. It uses composition as an alternative to inheritance. Decorators often provide additional APIs (methods) that are not available in the decorated classes.

On the other hand, AOP (e.g. an interceptor) is used to enhance existing behavior. It does not add additional APIs and generally does not modify existing functionality. It is triggered by invocation of existing functionality and responds by taking some action; but the existing functionality as well as the existing API remain unchanged.

I am not familiar with the JEE implementations, so they may have blurred the lines between these two patterns. Important points to compare would be,

- Can `@Interceptor` introduce new methods or only execute around existing methods?
- Can `@Interceptor` override existing methods or only append additional behavior?
- Can `@Decorator` be applied across packages & class hierarchies, or is it constrained by one of these?

In addition to functional differences between the two patterns, it may also be interesting to consider potential performance differences. I would expect `@Interceptor` to be considerably slower, since it needs to examine method calls at runtime, whereas `@Decorator` invocations can be resolved at compile time.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer contains too much speculation to be useful in the context of Java/Jakarta EE.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators very similar to interceptors with two interesting differences:

1. A decorator must implement the interface it is decorating (and yet can be abstract, so it does not have to implement the methods)
2. A decorator can have a reference to the object it decorates. It is done through injection

Ref: https://blog.frankel.ch/cdi-an-overview-part-2

Comment: But an interceptor can also get the reference with `ic.getTarget()`